# How to deal with NoClassDefFoundError when using OpenCSV (Maven)?

Tags: java, maven, noclassdeffounderror, opencsv

```java
try {
    CSVReader input = new CSVReader(new FileReader("s.csv"));
    String[] data;
    while (( data = input.readNext()) != null) {
        String id = data[0];
        String name = data[1];
        String password = data[2];
        String number = data[3];
        String gender = data[4];
        String mail = data[5];
        String department = data[6];
    }
    for(int i=0;i<data.length;i++)    //length is the property of the array  
        System.out.println(data[i]);

    System.out.println("==========================");
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println("hiiii");
}
```

I wanted to read the contents from a CSV file and print it in console. I have set the class path and everything is fine

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang3/ObjectUtils
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the complete stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Do you also have the dependencies for opencsv? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48674928/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-commons-lang3-objectutils

Comment: I have those dependencies to my mavean repository

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang3/ObjectUtils
        at com.opencsv.CSVParser.<init>(CSVParser.java:99)
        at com.opencsv.CSVReader.<init>(CSVReader.java:99)        at t.main(t.java:52)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang3.ObjectUtils        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)      java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)   at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ... 3 more

Comment: You either need to run it *with* Maven or package it with Maven Shade ( or similar fat jar) and run the jar

Comment: can you say it clearly @g00se

Comment: You're missing the Apache commons-lang3 dependency.